# MySql database structure - reverse engineer with foreign keys

Tags: mysql, dependencies, reverse-engineering

I have a MySql DB structure with foreign keys, how can I generate a diagram for it with table connections for foreign keys.

I need to clear the DB so have to find the table dependencies thats why I want to generate tables with connections.

There are keys in tables such as `KEY`FK228141202DDB7295

What is the tool for this?

Comment: Do you actually have foreign keys (e.g., does `show create table` have `foreign key` clauses in it or not?)

Answer (score 2):

Tools I know include [MySQL Workbench](http://wb.mysql.com/) and [SchemaSpy](http://schemaspy.sourceforge.net/). SchemaSpy is not MySQL specific and may be harder to set-up but it generates better graphs IMHO.